# Pandas Conditional Aggregation and Non Conditional Aggregation together

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, aggregate-functions, aggregation

I am a heavy SQL user and I am new to Python and Pandas. I have a DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd

data=[[1,100,'a'],[1,200,'b'],[2,300,'a'],[2,400,'a'],[3,500,'b'],[3,600,'a'],[3,700,'b']]

df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Group','Amount','Condition'])
```

Can I calculate both the conditional sum and 'regular' sum at one step?

Basically, in SQL, it will be like this.

```
select [Group]
,sum([Amount]) as Amount
,sum(case when [Condition]=’a’ then [Amount] end) as Conditional_Sum
from df
group by [Group]
```

But in Pandas, I split them into several steps.

For the 'regular' sum, I use

`df1=df.groupby('Group')['Amount'].sum().reset_index()`

For the conditional sum, I use

```
df2=df.groupby('Group').apply(lambda x: x[x['Condition']=='a']['Amount'].sum()).to_frame(name='Conditional_Sum')
df2.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Then I merge df1 and df2. Can I do this with just one step?

Edit: to clarify, is there a way to create below Data Frame within one step?

```
   Group  Amount  Conditional_Sum
0      1     300              100
1      2     700              700
2      3    1800              600
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use groupby apply and create Series with some columns

```
df.groupby('Group', as_index=False) \
  .apply(lambda x: pd.Series( \
        {'totalsum' : x['Amount'].sum(), \
         'condsum': x.loc[x['Condition']=='a','Amount'].sum()}))

       totalsum  condsum
0       300      100
1       700      700
2      1800      600
```

Comment: Thank you. I like this way.